# Вопрос по функции session_start в PHP

Tags: php

Привет.

Вопрос по функции `session_start()` в `PHP`. Я так понял, что, когда интерпретатор `PHP` видит функцию `session_start()`, то при отсутствии сессии создается поле `Set-Cookie:sessionid=...` в заголовке `http`-ответа сервера. Но поля заголовка `http` могут создаваться только ДО начала вывода данных в тело ответа сервера - до вывода в тело каких-либо символов (разметки, пробелов...). Получается, что тэги `<? ?>` должны идти в самом начале документа (БЕЗ пробелов перед ними), а внутри `<? ?>` ДО любого `echo` должен идти `session_start()`. Правильно я понимаю?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Во-первых, сессию можно хранить не в `cookie` (но чтобы там, надо использовать `session.use_cookies`, поиск по этому параметру приведет к остальным вариантам хранения), соответственно снимается ограничение на то, что нужно ничего не выводить в браузер до ее старта.

Во-вторых, да, нужно стартовать сессию, основанную на `cookie`, до любого вывода в браузер. Не забудьте, что у вас могут быть файлы в `include` или `require`, которые вроде бы содержать только php-код, но на самом деле в конце могут содержать пробел после закрывающего тега `?>`. Ради исключения таких ситуаций такие файлы обычно вообще оставляются без закрывающего тега.

Comment: "сессию можно хранить не в cookie" - как это осуществляется? я знаю только один вариант - это через куки

Comment: @Dimon обновил ответ. Вообще же, смотрите тут http://php.net/manual/ru/session.configuration.php - тем обширная, их где только не хранят, включая самописные обработчики сессий, устанавливаемые через http://php.net/manual/en/session.customhandler.php

Comment: @Dimon ты прав - первая фраза в этом ответе абсолютно бессмысленная, не имеющая отношения ни к твоему вопросу, ни к сессиям вообще, ни к здравому смыслу в целом. Пхпшники любят ляпнуть что-нибудь эдакое. Такая экосистема. привыкай.

Comment: @Ипатьев объясните, что вы имели ввиду.